# Structure of a semidirect product

Tags: group-theory

Assume that I have managed to show that a certain group $G$ is a semidirect product of $B$ by $S_n$ , where $B$ is a direct product of $n$ copies of a group $Z$, and $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ elements (I also know that $G$ is not abelian).

I'm not familiar with the theory of wreath products, but can I conclude directly that $G$ is isomorphic to $Z \wr S_n$, with the action of $S_n$ by permutation ? Or are there other structures of the form $Z \cdots Z \rtimes S_n$ which are not wreath products ?

Comment: There are other structures with that form. It is very unlikely to be referring to those. If $Z$ is infinite cyclic, there aren't even that many other possibilities. The wreath product is a specific action of $S_n$ on $B$ (the obvious, natural one that people care about). $S_n$ does usually have other actions on $B$, even beyond the trivial action giving the direct product.

Comment: There is one other slightly different action of $S_n$ on $Z^n$ (with $Z$ infinite cyclic): the module induced from the $1$-dimensional module for $S_{n-1}$ that maps odd permutations to $-I_1$. That gives rise to a so-called *twisted wreath product*.

Comment: I agree that is also a natural action. I calculate there are usually 4+2^(n+1) actions (1+c,s+c,1+sc,s+sc, and k*1+(n-k)*s, where 1 is the trivial rep, s is the sign rep, c is the natural irred rep, and k is a non-negative integer at most n). Currently I hold that three are in common use (1+c = wreath, s+sc = twisted wreath, and n*1 = direct).

Comment: Ah yes, so there are four distinct faithful modules giving rise to four nonisomorphic semidirect poducts.

Answer (score 0):

The unrestricted wreath product is equivalent to the semi-direct product. The restricted wreath product is formulated using the direct sum as a base of the wreath product. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product).